# accumarray(subs, val) where val has zeros

Tags: matlab, accumarray

I have a vector  `vv` containing market volume data for each tick, and a vector `minuteIdx` containing an index for different minutes. I'm using `accumarray` to sum the volume within each minute, like this:

```
orgMinuteVolumes = accumarray(minuteIdx, vv); %default function is @sum  
notrades = orgMinuteVolumes == 0;   
minuteVolumes = orgMinuteVolumes;
minuteVolumes(notrades) = [];
```

Usually it works perfectly, but occasionally volume data could not be obtained for all the  ticks in a minute, and there are `0`s in the volume vector. This results in the `minuteVolumes` vector being shorter than it would be otherwise since I got rid of all the zeros. For example if `vv` begins with a `1` (and there is only one tick in the first minute), then minuteVolumes is `175` long, but if I change `vv` to begin with a `0` then `minuteVolumes` is only `174` long. I want a `0` to appear in my `minuteVolumes` vector, not to make it shorter. Is there a smart way to make this happen? My original logic was that for a trade to occur volume had to be nonzero, but I didn't take into account occasional bad data.

Comment: This is confusing.  orgMinuteVolumes is, your example, 175 long, with a zero in the first element.  Then you have code specifically written to delete all your zero elements.  Now you're asking that the zeros not be deleted.  So... don't delete them.  Or there's more to your code/question that's not explicitly stated.

Comment: @Peter, my thoughts exactly, except I wasn't confident enough to ask.  siegel, seems like you're a bit of a "Quant" is that your full time job?

Comment: Sorry for the poorly thought out question, I'm going to work on this more and maybe ask another later. And no, I'm just working on this project as a hobby. I'm in college